# How to use app_data database in visual studio for signalR?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I have an mdf file in a folder and I want to use this in sqlDependency for signalR notification.  But it is not connecting via connection string.  Aslo, it is not showing in the database list (via a sql query).  When I run ALTER DATABASE crowdfunding SET ENABLE_BROKER;` I get an error:

> Msg 5011, Level 14, State 5, Line 1 User does not have permission to alter database 'crowdfunding', the database does not exist, or the database is not in a state that allows access checks. Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 ALTER DATABASE statement failed.

When I run in browser:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\crowdfunding.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share

Comment: Is the [database detected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-detach-and-attach-sql-server)?  Top tip: always include the error message.

Comment: This is the error when i run the file in browser.                                      An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\crowdfunding.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Comment: Msg 5011, Level 14, State 5, Line 1
User does not have permission to alter database 'crowdfunding', the database does not exist, or the database is not in a state that allows access checks.
Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
ALTER DATABASE statement failed.

Comment: Are the .mdf and SQL Server on the same machine?

Comment: Can you explain your question a little??What do you mean by on same machine?

Comment: The same computer.

Comment: Yes it is on same computer

Comment: Database get connected.I just add FULL ADDRESS at data directory in connection string.

Comment: Bu now it is causing problem in ENABLE_BROKER because it is in APP-DATA folder.Can you help me in this?